# ReactJS Tutorial Problems: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I'm trying to pull some data for nba player stats but I keep getting this "cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error and I'm not understanding why. I've done a similar tutorial the same way and had no issues, so I'm confused.
Here's the code:

```
function App() {


const [player, setPlayer] = useState([]);
  const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);



useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchStats() {
      let res = await fetch(`https://free-nba.p.rapidapi.com/stats/?format=json`, 
      {
        "method": "GET", 
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "free-nba.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "b9c32f403bmshdcd37fd74ccc767p1748b9jsn94ae938ec129"
        }
      });
      let data = await res.json();
      setPlayer(data.results);
      setLoading(false);

    }
fetchStats();
}, []);

return ( //Added where I'm calling Players 
    <>
      <Router> 
        <Navbar />
        <Container>
          {loading ? (
            <Dimmer active inverted>
              <Loader inverted>Loading</Loader>
            </Dimmer>
          ) : (
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/player'>
                <Players data={player} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/team'>
                <Teams data={team} />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          )}
        </Container>
      </Router>


    </>
  );
}
```

export default function Players({ data }) {
        return (
            <>

## Players

{data.map((player, i) => { **//This is where I get the error**
                        return (
                            
                                
                                    
                                        {player.first_name}
                                        
                                            **Height**

{player.height_feet}

**Position**

{player.position}

)
                    })}
                
            
        )

```
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing `<Players>` from?

Comment: The data that you are passing Players is undefined. I assume that this is because `data.results` does not exist. If you add the code where you are using the Players component, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: The code you've provided isn't syntactically valid (which would prevent us from reproducing the type error). Is it possible that we're looking at two files here and the `App` is properly closed? I'd expect most tutorials would have `App` render some JSX. Could you provide the tutorial you're working from?

Comment: I added where I'm using the Players component

Comment: This is the tutorial I learned this from: https://youtu.be/EC5ZvP87P2k

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. The API was returning data from an array called data.

So instead of setPlayer(data.results), I had to put setPlayer(data.data)